# Async return inside an iteration - Task ContinueWith inside ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, reactive-programming

The aim is to search for something specific with a bunch of keywords, but to do it reactively rather than waiting for the function to return something directly.

The following code considers a maximum of 3 keyword items inside the keywords parameter, but I need to loop through the keywords until all keywords have been searched (unless a positive result is returned before):

```
public void SearchForSomething(params string[] keywords)
{
    var index = -1;
    index = index + 1;
    if (keywords != null && keywords.Any())
    {
        var successTask = this.Search(keywords[index]);
        successTask.ContinueWith(
            task =>
            {
                if (!task.Result)
                {
                    index = index + 1;
                    if (index < keywords.Count())
                    {
                        var successTask2 = this.Search(keywords[index]);
                        successTask2.ContinueWith(
                            task2 =>
                            {
                                if (!task2.Result)
                                {
                                    index = index + 1;
                                    if (index < keywords.Count())
                                    {
                                        var successTask3 = this.Search(keywords[index]);
                                        successTask3.ContinueWith(
                                            task3 =>
                                            {
                                                if (!task3.Result)
                                                {
                                                    this.NotifyNada(keywords);
                                                }
                                            });
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        this.NotifyNada(keywords);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.NotifyNada(keywords);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
    else
    {
        this.NotifyNada(keywords);
    }
}
```

How to search say 50 keyword strings?

- asynchronously, but still in sequential order (not in parallel)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: @Fabjan reactive programming instead of using a search function that synchronously returns the result and blocks on each keyword

Comment: Are you using .NET 4.5?  On first glance, this looks trivial using async/await.  Loop through each keyword, await the result of `Search`, if it's false then break and call `NotifyNada`.

Comment: @CharlesMager it might be trivial, but I'm not seeing it - could you provide an answer with code please

Comment: Reactive programming has nothing to do with performing searches asynchronously

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have miscommunicated by not including the Search(keyword) and NotifyNada methods' code, which actually use a reactive Subject so that listeners could observe a stream of results - the full code is actually reactive..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I mentioned you might be able to come up with a simple solution using async/await.  I haven't studied the code in huge detail, but it seems to me this is effectively what you're doing:

```
public async Task SearchForSomething(params string[] keywords)
{
    foreach (var keyword in keywords)
    {
        if (await Search(keyword))
        {
            // If we have a result, we return
            return;
        }
    }
    // If we didn't find, notify?
    NotifyNada(keywords);
}
```

Comment: This is good point too

Comment: Changed the code a bit to match the OP's, does seem like a weird method though :)

Comment: @flindeberg thanks - I've read it again and your edit seems to be correct!

Comment: the original intent was to run everything asynchronously after the first Search(keyword) has been called and have no return type whatsoever, but the burden of running the foreach loop and the NotifyNada on the calling thread should be minimal, so this works great. thanks!

Comment: This is still asynchronous.  Remember Task != Thread - [there is no thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).  If there are threads involved and this is running on a UI thread and you don't want subsequent searches resuming on the captured UI thread context, you could use `Search.ConfigureAwait(false)`.